# Django rest framework datatables foreign key data could not be obtained

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, datatables

My problem here is when i add a foreign key to my table i face issues like not getting value and not filtering the table below i share the models and serializers.

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=77, unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"

class Process(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class ProcessSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Process
        fields = '__all__'

<th data-data="foo.name" data-name="foo.name">Foo</th>
```

I am adding a foreign key to my model then utilize djangorestframework-datatables package i can not get the name attribute i just get an id like "1" for the foreign key and after adding .name to the foo model in data-data i could not get any value. I get the following error

```
DataTables warning: table id=processes - Requested unknown parameter 'foo.name' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4
```

I don't see any problem in the code any help is appreciated.

Table properties:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Processes</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Processes">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <table id="processes" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%" data-server-side="true" data-ajax="/api/processes/?format=datatables">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th data-data="foo.name" data-name="foo.name">Foo</th>
              <th data-data="process">Process</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#processes').DataTable();
      });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please show the whole html section you are rendering? Is `data-ajax` set correctly?

Comment: Hi, i added the html section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you looking for is [**Nested Relationships**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)

You will need to include a `FooSerializer` class and update your `ProcessSerializer`

```
...

# Include this class
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = '__all__'

class ProcessSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    foo = FooSerializer(read_only=True) # serialize the Foo Object

    class Meta:
        model = Process
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the update. I got the error "Foo object is not iterable"

Comment: After removing the many=True the problem is resolved i will update the post further.

Comment: @tealy Yeah, my bad... I didn't even noticed the `models.ForeignKey` at the first time. Sorry for the bad code.